# What will I need to do to make a international-to-domestic connection at GRU?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, connecting-flights, brazil, gru

My wife and I are flying BOS–GRU–GIG soon.  Our tickets were purchased as a single itinerary from LATAM. 
As we do not speak very much Portuguese, it would help us to know what to expect as we make the connection at GRU.  Specifically:

- We will clear customs & immigration upon arrival in GRU, presumably.  Will we need to reclaim and re-check our luggage as part of this process?  If so, do we need to take our baggage to the departures hall, or is there a place near the international arrivals area to re-check bags?
- It appears that we will be arriving in Terminal 3 and departing from Terminal 2 (correct me if I'm wrong here.)  Is there a way to transfer airside between these terminals, or will we have to exit security in Terminal 3 and then re-enter security in Terminal 2?

Answer (score 2):

It is a very late answer by now, but for the sake of others with the similar doubts here it is:

- When entering Brazil (next flight is domestic), in the first port of entry you always: (1) go through immigration checks, (2) reclaim luggage, (3) clear customs, (4) re-dispatch luggage.

  In the case of GRU, most if not all domestic airlines have a transfer desk after customs where you can re-check your bags.
- GRU has no airside transfer from  international to domestic. (I think no airport in Brazil does.) You are going to leave airside, go landside, and go through the whole process for a domestic flight (including security).